# How to restrict HTML/Javascript insertion in database table Laravel 5.2

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I could successfully save html/javascript into the database table and it renders it. This is for the first time I have moved to Laravel, YII frameworks automatically caters it but how can I do the same thing in Laravel?

I don't want to use specific checks all over my application, there must be some centralized approach to do so.

[image]

Output:

[image]

`htmlentities($inputs['first_name']);` that does the job but how to do this in the whole app. I don't want to have these checks everywhere.

That's how I render form:

```
            {!! Form::model($companyUser, ['route' => ['updateUserProfile', $companyUser->id], 'method' => 'put', 'class' => 'frm-container']) !!}
            <div class="col-lg-5">
            {!! Form::controlRequired('text', 0, 'first_name', $errors, 'First Name') !!}
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
            {!! Form::control('text', 0, 'last_name', $errors,  'Last Name') !!}
              </div>
                  <br clear="all"/>
              <div class="col-lg-5">
            {!! Form::control('password', 0, 'password', $errors,  'New Password') !!}
            </div>
              <div class="col-lg-5">
            {!! Form::control('password', 0, 'password_confirmation', $errors,  'Confirm Password') !!}
            </div>
           <br clear="all"/>
            <div class="col-lg-12 btn-frm-inner">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit">Update</button>
            <a href="<?= URL::to('/');?>" class="btn btn-cancel">Cancel</a>
            </div>

            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: can you share some code ?

Comment: We are using ORM on the back-end so we are basically filling objects and storing them..

Comment: ok make sure that your field name is mention in your Model file.

Comment: How are you displaying it with blade? using {{ }} should automatically escape it, whereas {!! !!} doesn't :)

Comment: @phpdeveloper updated it ..added the encoding part that works fine

Comment: @Jazerix how about if I use php tags?

Comment: Please include something from your view. You're not supposed to have more logic than if else foreach and so on in your view. Anything else needs to be done elsewhere.

Comment: If you're using php tags, you're doing it wrong ^^

Comment: @Jazerix posted the view's code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is from the form.

You're not supposed to filter what's going in the database in my opinion. You should simply let anything come and then display it the way you want. So this is fine.

Now as for displaying the data :

`{{ }}` will escape automatically, while `{!! !!}` will NOT escape anything.

So when you display the data in your view, you should use the first option.